# Microsoft Licensing - Can I use the wrong product key?

Tags: licensing

We are in the process of moving our Microsoft software licensing from [Microsoft Action Pack Subscription](https://partner.microsoft.com/40016455) to [Open Value Licensing](https://partner.microsoft.com/global/licensing/licensingprograms/ltvolumelicensing/vlopenvalue). We have enough licenses for all the software that we have purchased via OVL, but we still have the MAPS installations on our systems.

To be fully license compliant, is having the licenses enough to satisfy anybody that came to audit our licensing, or do I need to remove the MAPS versions and re-install the systems with the OVL software, even though the versions are essentially identical?

Obviously, if we don't reinstall, the product keys won't match, but does this matter as long as we have the licenses to use this software?

Comment: I've voted to close this question, simply because all licensing questions should be aimed at your Microsoft partner, as they are -always- the best to ask.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Comment: @pauska: Rather than vote to close the question, why not post 'You need to speak to your Microsoft Partner' as an answer, that way this information is here on SF for others thinking of asking the exact same question?

Comment: @Graeme: I disagree, as the other question makes no reference to the specifics of the question I've asked.

Comment: the whole point of Graeme pointing to that duplicate (and that is actually automatic when you vote to close as duplicate) is that the question it points to is the canonical answer to this question "Talk to MS" instead of repeating that in each question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion it wouldn't matter. Have you tried to change the keys in products?

But to be 100% sure you should call your local Microsoft and ask them. They have this nice feature that your "call" can be saved and assigned to your Windows Live Login so any answer that they will give you will be something you can always use when talking to auditors.

Comment: Thanks, rather than take any chances, I'll speak to somebody who has to take responsibility for the answer they give me.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft don't use auditing very easily, actually Microsoft would use MAP License "Usage Pattern Report", which is based by trusting the number of licenses used, supplied by customer, rather than auditing in the first place.

**Microsoft Open Value agreement states that**:
`"For the company-wide option, customers must standardize desktop platform products on all desktop PCs across their organizations and must order licenses for all qualified devices that can run any of the chosen desktop platform products."`

There are no refunds after you have accessed the **MAPS** software download site. If you cancel your subscription, `the software licenses are no longer valid and you must uninstall all copies of the software.`

Action Pack subscriptions end when you don't renew, you can not use the software in any manner, not even an upgrade.

To be fully licensed you must re-install software using the currently valid software and license keys.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ask your auditors? Afterall, they're the ones enforcing the rules so they should know them best.